# Using Crypto++ with clang

Tags: macos, crypto++, undefined-symbol, clang++, missing-symbols

I'm attempting to get the following Crypto++ (C++ Class Library of Cryptographic Schemes) example to work on a iMac using clang++.

Example

```
SHA256 hash;

byte digest[ SHA256::DIGESTSIZE ];

hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) &value[ 0 ], value.size( ) );

HexEncoder encoder;

string result = String::empty;

encoder.Attach( new StringSink( result ) );

encoder.Put( digest, sizeof( digest ) );

encoder.MessageEnd( );
```

Build command

```
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.7.4 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name checksum_impl.cpp -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 123.2.1 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/2.1 -D framework_EXPORTS -I /Users/Ben/Dropbox/appon/build/../source -nostdinc++ -cxx-isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic -std=c++0x -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 175 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o CMakeFiles/framework.dir/Users/Ben/Dropbox/source/example.cpp.o -x c++ /Users/Ben/Dropbox/source/example.cpp
clang -cc1 version 2.1 based upon llvm 3.0svn hosted on x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/Ben/Dropbox/build/../source
 /usr/include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/2.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Linker output

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-std=c++0x'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelCreatePutSpace(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long&)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPut2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPutModifiable2(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, int, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelMessageSeriesEnd(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
  "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::SetRetrievalChannel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in checksum_impl.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using the latest development version of Crypto++ 5.6.2 as the previous version 5.6.1 fails to build with clang++. However i'm encountering build issues stating that i have missing symbols for x86_64 architecture.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was relating to Crypto++ not having been ported over to llvm-clang++. The supported compilers are listed on [Platforms](https://cryptopp.com/#platforms); supported compilers for previous releases are listed on [Compiling](http://web.archive.org/web/20190216033540/http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Compiling).

My solution was to instead use [GCrypt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/).

Sorry I can't supply anymore details on the cause of the failure.

Comment: This answer is of no help to anyone else who runs into the same issue. Can you elaborate on what the cause of the problem was, and what the solution is?

Comment: The first link takes to a page that says *There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs, but you do not have permission to create this page.*

Answer (score 3):

Crypto++ 5.6.2 successfully build on LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) with make options:

```
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -Wno-c++11-narrowing"
```

accordingly this script: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik-packaging/blob/master/osx/scripts/build_cryptopp.sh

-stdlib=libstdc++ need for MacOSX since Mavericks, see: [When is it necessary to use use the flag -stdlib=libstdc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstdc)

Answer (score 2):

you need to link to the library that provides those symbols, which should be libcryptopp.so, using`-lcryptopp` in the compiler command

Looking at your "build command" (which is not the command you're running, it's the *output* of the command you're running, it would be a lot easier to read if you showed the actual command) it seems you are compiling a `.cpp` file into a `.o` file, but getting a linker error, which is strange as producing a `.o` file is usualy the step *before* linking. What step are you trying to do?  Maybe you also need to add `-c` so it only compiles and doesn't try to link.  You will still need `-lcryptopp` when linking.

Comment: Oh :s sorry, Jonathan Wakely I'd forgot I placed this question here. The cause is down to poor support for llvm-clang++. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jonathon's answer because this is a fairly prevalent problem *when* `-lcryptopp` is specified...

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)"`...

The `__1` indicates you are using the LLVM C++ runtime (`libc++`). Somewhere, you are probably mixing and matching with the GNU C++ runtime (`libstdc++`). The GNU C++ runtime (`libstdc++`) lacks the `__1` decoration on its symbols.

You should go through the project ***and*** all pre-built libraries, and ensure they are using one or the other. For each, you should use `CXXFLAGS` of either (1) `-stdlib=libc++` (LLVM), or (2) `-stdlib=libstdc++` (GNU).

Be aware that IDEs like Xcode may use a different `-stdlib=...` setting than Crypto++. In this case, have Xcode match Crypto++, or rebuild the Crypto++ library to match Xcode.

If Xcode is using LLVM's `libc++` and you have to rebuild Crypto++, then open the `GNUmakefile` and rework this section (around line 90):

```
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
  AR = libtool
  ARFLAGS = -static -o
  CXX = c++
  IS_GCC2 = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c gcc-932)
ifeq ($(IS_GCC2),1)
    CXXFLAGS += -fno-coalesce-templates -fno-coalesce-static-vtables
    LDLIBS += -lstdc++
    LDFLAGS += -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -m
endif
endif
```

If you want to use LLVM's `libc++`, then remove:

```
# GNU C++ Runtime
LDLIBS += -lstdc++
```

And add:

```
# LLVM C++ Runtime
CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
```

For completeness, if you want to use GNU's runtime, then remove the `LDLIBS += -lstdc++` and add `CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++`.

You can also change `CXX = c++` to `CXX ?= c++` so the makefile will use `c++` *if* its not specified in the environment or command line.

---

If interested, the `__1` is an inline namespace used for versioning. See [What are inline namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11016220) and [Where does the __1 symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29293394).