# Wherefore inline unnamed namespaces?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, inline-namespaces

A quick one for the gurus: C++11 allows unnamed namespaces to be declared `inline`. This seems redundant to me; things declared in an unnamed namespace are already used as if they were declared in the enclosing namespace.

So my question is this: what does it mean to say

```
inline namespace /*anonymous*/ {
    // stuff
}
```

and how is it different from the traditional

```
namespace /*anonymous*/ {
    // stuff
}
```

that we know and love from C++98? Can anyone give an example of different behaviour when `inline` is used?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, since this question has been marked as a duplicate: I'm not asking about *named* inline namespaces in general. I understand the use-case there, and I think they're great. I'm specifically asking what it means to declare an *unnamed* namespace as `inline`. Since unnamed namespaces are necessarily always local to a TU, the symbol versioning rational doesn't seem to apply, so I'm curious about what adding `inline` actually *does*.

---

As an aside, the standard [7.3.1.1], regarding unnamed namespaces, says:

> `inline` appears if and only if it appears in the *unnamed-namespace-definition*

but this seems like a tautology to my non-language lawyer eyes -- "it appears in the definition iff it appears in the definition"! For bonus points, can anyone explain what this bit of standardese is actually saying?

**EDIT:** Cubbi claimed the bonus point in the comments:

> the standard is saying that *unnamed-namespace-definition* behaves as if it were replaced by **X** where `inline` appears in **X** iff it appears in the *unnamed-namespace-definition*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are inline namespaces for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for)

Comment: @Jefffrey, This is about *unnamed* inline namespaces.

Comment: @chris, I think you can mix the definition of *unnamed* and *inline* namespaces to come up with the answer.

Comment: @Jefffrey That question is regarding inline namespaces in general, which I understand. This question is specifically asking what it means for an *unnamed* namespace to be `inline`, which doesn't seem to be covered by the linked answers (or any other SO question I could find).

Comment: The bonus point is easy: the standard is saying that *unnamed-namespace-definition* behaves as if it were replaced by **X** where `inline` appears in **X** iff it appears in the *unnamed-namesace-definition*

Comment: @Cubbi That actually makes sense, and probably would have clicked if I'd thought about it some more, rather than just reading it and going "huh?". Thanks, have yourself a bonus point! :-)

Comment: @Jefffrey if you can mix the definitions and come up an answer then please post it, because this is precisely what I'm asking! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one use that I have found:

```
namespace widgets { inline namespace {

void foo();

} } // namespaces

void widgets::foo()
{
}
```

In this example, `foo` has internal linkage and we can define the function later on by using the `namespace::function` syntax to ensure that the function's signature is correct. If you were to not use the `widgets` namespace then the `void foo()` definition would define a totally different function. You also don't need to re-open the namespace saving you a level of indentation.

If there is another function called `foo` in the widgets `namespace` already then this will give you an ambiguity instead rather than a nasty ODR violation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing here. Why is the inner `inline namespace` necessary?

Comment: @templatetypedef the inner `inline namespace` gives `foo` internal linkage. The outer `namespace` is so that you can use the `namespace::function` syntax to define it, ensuring you get the signature correct.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. You might want to update your answer to explicitly indicate this, since I didn't pick that up the first time around.

Comment: Cool, I like this! Clang doesn't seem to though: I get *"out-of-line definition of 'foo' does not match any declaration in namespace 'widgets'"*. It works just fine with g++ though, so maybe it's just a Clang bug.

Comment: @TristanBrindle: Is that [this Clang bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17560)?

Comment: I agree this is useful, but is the inline actually necessary here? It seems like it will work the same way without keyword inline.

Comment: @NirFriedman without the `inline` you can't define the `foo` function without opening the unnamed namespace again.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know whether it's the done thing to answer your own question on SO, but after some playing around my curiosity has been satisfied, so I may as well share it.

The definition of an inline namespace includes not only the hoisting of names into the enclosing namespace (which happens anyway for unnamed namespaces), but also allows templates defined within an inline namespace to be specialised outside it. It turns out that this applies to unnamed namespaces too:

```
inline // comment this out to change behaviour
namespace { 
    template <typename T> struct A {};
}

template <> struct A<int> {};
```

Without the `inline`, g++ complains about trying to specialise a template from a different namespace (though Clang does not). With `inline`, it compiles just fine. With both compilers, anything defined within the specialisation is still marked as having *internal linkage* (according to `nm`), as if it were within the unnamed namespace, but I guess this is to be expected. I can't really think of any reason why this would be useful, but there we go.

An arguably more useful effect comes from the change regarding *argument-dependent lookup* for inline namespaces, which also affects unnamed inline namespaces. Consider the following case:

```
namespace NS {
    // Pretend this is defined in some header file
    template <typename T>
    void func(const T&) {}

    // Some type definition private to this TU
    inline namespace {
        struct A {};
    }

} // end namespace NS

int main()
{
    NS::A a;
    func(a);
}
```

Without `inline`, ADL fails and we have to explicitly write `NS::func(a)`. Of course, if we defined the unnamed namespace at the toplevel (as one normally would), then we wouldn't get ADL whether it was inline or not, but still...