# Where does the __1 symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?

Tags: c++, symbols, libstdc++, libc++

I see a fair amount of questions like [Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15070556) and [Undefined symbols in cryptopp at IOS 64-bit project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28311795). The problem is usually described as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      cv::gpu::error(char const*, char const*, int, char const*) in opencv2(gpumat.o)
```

The problem often reduces to mixing/matching `-stdlib=libc++` (LLVM C++ runtime) and `-stdlib=libstdc++` (GNU C++ runtime). The LLVM C++ runtime (`libc++`) has an `__1` decoration symbol, but the GNU C++ runtime `libstdc++` *lacks* the `__1` symbol in its name. It causes linker problems for symbols that appears to have the same name (like `std::string`).

Where does the `__1` symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?

Why was the problem *not* solved with a `gnu` namespace and an `llvm` namespace?

---

Here's a related question: [libc++ - stop std renaming to std::__1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9000816). But it kind of misses the point in that a rename does not occur.

Comment: It's an inline namespace that libc++ uses for versioning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is from C++11 inlined namespaces

libc++ has something like

```
namespace std {
    inline namespace __1 {
        ....
```

more at [What are inline namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for)

Comment: Thanks @Severin. That's an interesting link. So *if* I used a C++11 compiler, the the problems with `std::string` and `std::__1::string` would go away becuase the compiler would understand the inline namespace? Or the problem would go away if I used `-std=c++03` because inline namespaces would not be used? (Up until now, I've been telling people to compile everything with either the LLVM runtime or the GNU runtime).

Comment: @jww I believe both compilers (GCC and clang) understand inlined namspaces. Problem is with declaration vs definition. If you're using libc++ headers, you'll get declarations picked with `std::__1::`  prefix, something like `std::__1::string` etc. If  you're using GNU libstdc++ header, you'll get declaration `std::string` etc. But then you have to pick up definitions from either libstdc++.a/.so or from libc++.a/.so. Due to the fact, that each library is compiled with it's own headers, definitions also carry the same prefix. To be continued...

Comment: Thus, if you pick declarations from libc++ headers (with std::__1:: prefix) but try to use definitions from libstdc++ (with std:: prefix), you're getting linker error - definitions don't much. Good thing, I think, debugging might be a nightmare. So I would say if you're using GNU toolchain, link against libstdc++, if clang - link against libc++

Comment: Just to be clear - those prefixes are in mangled names in compiled code in .o/.a/.so. In source code you see/use std::string.

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution to the resulting compilation problem, though.